# Integrate Admob to existing Code - React / JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, admob, banner-ads

I am trying to add the banner add to my code, however all tutorials and guides online show it with a blank page. My page already has certain code and functions (consts and reducers), and I have been trying for a long time to merge everything together , but am not much experienced.

Ad Code:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, Component } from "react";
import { AdMobBanner } from "expo-ads-admob";

class AdScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.bannerAdId =
            Platform.OS === "ios"
                ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
                : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <AdMobBanner
                    bannerSize="BannerAdSize.FULL_BANNER"
                    adUnitID={this.bannerAdId}
                    servePersonalizedAds={false}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "increment":
            return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
        case "submit":
            return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const CounterScreen = () => {
    const initialState = { count: 0 };
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [names, setName] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState("");

    const submittosheet = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                "https://v1.nocodeapi.com?tabId=Sheet1",
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify([
                        [names, age, state.count, new Date().toLocaleString()],
                    ]),
                }
            );
            await response.json();
            console.log(response);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <Text/>

            <TextInput/>

            <Button/>

        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

Please any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Rashid banner ads take some take to appear on your site. + In your code you didn't include AdScreen component in your CounterCcreen component.

Comment: Hi brother,  thanks for your reply. As I am not very experienced, I am not able to include both components in one screen without errors. My main code is the counterscreen, and the adscreen code i obtained from documentation and tutorials. Please any guide on how to combine both in one screen would be appreciated.